# Присвоить массиву только цифры из другого массива

Tags: python

Написать программу которая:
Вводит символьный массив с 16 элементов и строит другой массив, который будет содержать только цифры, которые содержатся в первом массиве
Не могу понять как присвоить другому массиву только цифры

```
import re

S=re.sub('[^0-9]','','h5e2llo24wor86ld')
```

Comment: ваш код извлекает только цифры из строки - что с ним не так?

Comment: Нужно чтобы цифры из массива S были присвоены другому массиву

Comment: под массивом вы понимаете список? `lst = list(re.sub('[^0-9]','','h5e2llo24wor86ld'))` или `[x for x in s if x.isdigit()]`

Comment: Если через регулярки: `items = list(map(int, re.findall('\d','h5e2llo24wor86ld')))`. findall вернет список строк с цифрами, map с int к каждому элементу списка применит int, а list приведет результат к обычному списку. Тоже самое, но через генератор списка: items = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d','h5e2llo24wor86ld')]

Comment: Нужно создать  список ,в него ввести с клавиатуры символы. Затем взять из этого списка только цифры и поместить их в другой список

Answer (score 2):

если вы хотите получить список целых цифр, которые содержаться в строке:

```
In [51]: s = 'h5e2llo24wor86ld'

In [52]: res = [int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()]

In [53]: print(res)
[5, 2, 2, 4, 8, 6]
```